# How to send a reminder 45 days before the event ---- formula field does not trigger the process builder

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, email-alert

I have created a custom object "Assigned tasks" that works like tasks such that it has due date, subject, priority e.t.c. This custom object "Assigned tasks" is a child object to case object. Case object has a date/time field called "Event start date". I want the system to keep checking the due date of the assigned task and the value in Event start date on the case level. when there are only 45 days left in the event start date and status of task is pending, it should send an email alert/reminder to the assignee of the task that they have to complete the task.

I created a formula field(Checkbox) on the assigned task object:

IF(AND(OR(TEXT(Status__c) ='Pending', TEXT(Status__c) = 'Waiting on Someone'),  DATEVALUE(Case__r.Event_Start_Date__c -45) = TODAY()),true, false)

Then in process builder , I am trying to check if the formula above/checkbox is true, it sends an email alert.

The issue is that the checkbox does get selected 45 days prior to event start date but it does not  trigger the process builder to send an email alert.Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how scheduled actions work (workflow or process builder). Instead, you need to set the criteria not including the date:

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Pending"),ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Waiting on someone"))
```

Make sure you check the advanced option for "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?"

Next, add a formula to your object to get the date:

```
Case__r.Event_Start_Date__c
```

Finally, in the scheduled action area, specify "45 Days Before Event Start Date".

As a special note, if the case's value changes, the flow won't "notice" this unless you also update the child records. You may want to set up a separate process to do this to make sure the dates are updated appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you are saying. However, I wonder if the existing task records that are already in 'Pending' or 'Waiting on someone' status would still trigger this?

Comment: @Student No, it would only affect future records. Again, this is how the platform works; PB can only fire when a record is created or modified.

Comment: so does that mean I will have to write Batch Apex Scheduler code?

Comment: @Student Typically, you should be able to use the Data Loader to touch the records and queue them. Also, a scheduler would be pointless, since you'd only need it for at most 45 days.

Comment: ok so let's say if I try to achieve it using workflow or process builder and the records are touched in any way, my concern is when the task is created, its status by default is pending. So even if I edit the record and the record is already in pending state, would it still trigger the code? because in the criteria we are checking if the record goes to pending state(e.g from New to Pending ) not when its already in pending state. I don't have any New state. The first task status in my case is Pending, then either waiting on someone or completed.

Comment: Let's say if the task is created today with a pending state but there are still 60 days left to event start date, the code won't do anything. Now when the days pass by and there are 45 days left, would it trigger the code?

Comment: @Student You'll want to read [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1) and related links. In the case of existing records, you have to update them to not match the criteria, then again to match the criteria. For new records (e.g. 60 days out), the record is placed in the queue, and at the appropriate time, the alert would be sent out. The help link I just linked to explains in more detail.